# createdb with collation "C"

Tags: postgresql, powershell, collate

I'm trying to create a PostgreSQL database through PowerShell  with collate option as C to address sorting order of fields with special characters using below command:

```
createdb -U postgres -h localhost -p 5432 -O apm apm -l 'C' -T template0
```

But seeing below error:

> createdb: too many command-line arguments (first is "C")

Postgres version: 9.6.6
OS: Windows 10

Comment: You have `apm` there twice.

Comment: yes. one is referring to role and other is referring to database name. 
I tried below and database got created without issues:
    'createdb -U postgres -h localhost -p 5432 -O apm apm'. But I'm unable to create database with collate option C

Comment: After the database name, should come the description and **that's all**.

Comment: Is it even possible to give the collate option in `createdb`?  I don't see anything about it in the docs.

Comment: I guess, yes. [link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-createdb.html)

Comment: `-lc-collate` takes a locale.

Comment: Must be a Windows thing - your command works on my Linux. Have you tried putting the database name last?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
createdb -U postgres -h localhost -p 5432 -O apm apm -lc-collate='C' -T template0
```

Comment: Got this error: createdb: too many command-line arguments (first is "-T")